# iptables geoip blocks all but the countries i listed ok, but blocks apt updates?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables

Thought id block all connections bar those from the US and AU, and that part works, but i can no longer run apt updates and pinging google from the terminal fails

What am i missing here? If i remove the geoip line all works...the apt mirror btw is in the US, hosted on the digitalocean server im running from...

Any help appreciated

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc AU,US -j LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-dropped: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

the results of a ping to google and then an apt-get install are:

```
Jan  3 12:18:33 wifi kernel: [ 6083.707903] iptables-dropped: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.53 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35873 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51564 DPT=53 LEN=64
Jan  3 12:19:13 wifi kernel: [ 6123.745110] iptables-dropped: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.53 LEN=67 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38624 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=36189 DPT=53 LEN=47
Jan  3 12:19:33 wifi kernel: [ 6144.125699] iptables-dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=42:40:27:b3:46:91:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=117.50.110.5 DST=198.199.71.101 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=42 ID=59012 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47926 DPT=80 WINDOW=28280 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Jan  3 12:20:04 wifi kernel: [ 6175.132445] iptables-dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=42:40:27:b3:46:91:fe:00:00:00:01:01:08:00 SRC=117.50.110.5 DST=198.199.71.101 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=44 ID=734 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33934 DPT=80 WINDOW=28280 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

As requested, with iptables-save -c output:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [33:1936]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:260]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
[27:2919] -A INPUT -m geoip ! --source-country AU,US  -j LOGGING
[269:136906] -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j     ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2010 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
[261:18115] -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[22:2420] -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
[5:550] -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-dropped: "
[27:2919] -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Comment: I can detect one issue but maybe a second lurks around. So the first thing to do is to give the final resulting configuration: `iptables-save -c` to not have any doubt ( [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/686162/edit) the question ).

Comment: Edited OP with requested iptables-save -c output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your script *inserts* as first rule a rule allowing packets only from AU and US. This doesn't include packets from 127.0.0.0/8 used on the loopback interface. All other rules appearing later are thus never used: the needed packets are already dropped.

So for example DNS resolution involving the client 127.0.0.1 to the local DNS server 127.0.0.53 fails and there's no way to use correctly a query having to resolve any hostname.

---

Replace:

> ```
> iptables -I INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc AU,US -j LOGGING
> ```

with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc AU,US -j LOGGING
```

still keeping it at the same place in the script. That way it won't bypass the stateful rule which allow only packets from previously established connections **including locally initiated *outgoing* connections to outside of AU and US** and the rule for the loopback interface which is needed for various local services including the local DNS server. It will still block anything not from AU/US before rules allowing specific services.

Also, as a simple remark, since the default policy in the OUTPUT chain is ACCEPT and there's no rule with a DROP target there, the two rules in the OUTPUT chain are currently useless.

Comment: Cheers, that that worked perfectly!, and point taken on the unnecessary OUTPUT rules, i was whittling my way through things form a default set of rules, and iptables remains a dark art to me, one of the few things i find tricky to grasp.....

Truly appreciated